# Replacing gethostbyname to getaddrinfo for ICMP (IcmpSendEcho)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock2, icmp

The legacy code has `gethostbyname` to get IP address of a host. The integer part of converted address is then passed to `IcmpSendEcho`. 
I am replacing this obsolete function with `getaddrinfo`.

```
DWORD GetIPAddressInt(const char* pAddress)
{
    PADDRINFOA addr = nullptr;    
    addrinfo hints = { 0 };

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;    
    // hints.ai_socktype = ??;
    // hints.ai_protocol = ??;
    getaddrinfo(pAddress, nullptr, &hints, &addr);

    auto sockaddr_ipv4 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addr->ai_addr);

    return sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
}
```

My question is: What about `ai_socktype` and `ai_protocol` members?

- Should socket type be `SOCK_RAW` ?
- Should protocol be `IPPROTO_ICMP` (In header, not in MSDN) ?

Re-iterating again, that the resultant IP address will be used for sending ICMP echo request, and hence I am wondering if RAW/ICMP are needed? For now, IPv6 is not a worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning documentation for **getaddrinfo** you could just leave this fields blank (0).

> A value of zero for ai_socktype indicates the caller will accept any socket type.
>
> A value of zero for ai_protocol indicates the caller will accept any protocol.

IPv4 and IPv6 address doesn't depends on whether is used for stream or specific protocol type. So for calling `IcmpSendEcho` just ignore this fields.

**Edit:**

The socket type and protocol hint may be relevant only if the service name is specified. Service names could be "http", "tftp" etc. If you specify "tftp" service for example, you can not set "stream" socket type since tftp is datagram based. But in your case (and may be most other time) service field is left NULL. If you specify "http" service for example, the port member in ai_addr.sin_port should be filled too.

Comment: I read that part in docs, but I got confused with the word "any". Does it mean `getaddrinfo` will return IP for all prototype/socket-type? What is the intelligence, that may be applied by `getaddreinfo` ?

Comment: @Ajay Since `getaddrinfo` provides "protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address" and since an IPv4 address doesn't change for specific protocols or socket types, protocol and socket type hints should be ignored. However as stated in the documentation I would set it to zero (indicates to accept any), otherwise and error like `EAI_SOCKTYPE` may be returned (didn't tested).

Comment: @Ajay You can find more information about the implementation of `getaddrinfo` in the RFC 2553.